# How do we say "Product Detail Page"?

Tags: english-to-german

How can I translate this to Germany?

```
Amazon Product Detail Page
```

This will direct link to amazon website product page

```
Beschreibungsseite eines Amazon.de?
```

?

Comment: I don't get the question. Do you want an explanation or a way to phrase that in German. Also, it is not a sentence

Comment: @Emanuel a translation how can I say that in german?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Amazon Germany](http://www.amazon.de/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_left_cn?ie=UTF8&nodeId=200104190) calls it

> Produkt-Detailseite

[Here'](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_rel_topic?ie=UTF8&nodeId=10683361)s the English page for comparison.

Comment: Produkt-Detailseite Amazon.de Will be fine?

Comment: @Markus I think Amazon Produkt-Detailseite works better in a sentence... or Produkt-Detailseite bei Amazon. Depending on context even Produktbeschreibung alone might be the best choice.

Comment: @Markus... forget my last comment. Reading through the page I get the strong impression that Amazon wants it called (Produkt)-Detailseite ... they do not use "Beschreibung" there.

Answer (score 0):

Possible translations: *Amazon-Produktbeschreibungsseite* or *Beschreibungsseite eines Amazon-Produktes*.

Comment: can I use the following? `Beschreibungsseite eines Amazon.de?`

Comment: If you want to use _Amazon.de_, you need to write _Beschreibungsseite von Amazon.de_.

Comment: Use the one above, I didn't get your point...

Answer (score 0):

#### Produktdetail-Seite

The Amazon translation to *"Produkt-Detailseite"* is incorrect. When using a hyphen to clarify relations between nouns after building a composite such as **"Produktdetailseite"** (which would be fine grammatically) we should take care to not change the meaning by putting the hyphen on the wrong place.

What we want is a detail of a product (*"Produktdetail"*) on an own page, its not about a product on a detailed page (*"Detailseite"*).

Hence when hyphenating we can only say: **"Produktdetail-Seite"**

Comment: I think they did it because they keep using Detailseite throught the page even without the "Produkt" but they felt "Produktdetailseite" would be too long and clumsy... I'd actually spell it Produktde-Tailseite

Comment: @Emanuel: that may well be the case. But now we'd need someone to explain what a *"Detailseite"* is. Its beyond my imagination.